# Why does StyleCop output read "StyleCop cancelled"?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, stylecop

In VisualStudio 2012, creating a WPF solution, attempting to run stylecop on entire solution, the output reads

```
------ StyleCop 4.7 (build 4.7.59.0) started ------

Pass 1:   testProject - \App.xaml.cs
Pass 1:   testProject - \Modules\Administration\Models\DocumentClass.cs
Pass 1:   testProject - \Modules\Administration\Models\DocumentType.cs
Pass 1:   testProject - \Modules\Administration\Models\LetterGroup.cs
Pass 1:   testProject - \Modules\Administration\Models\LetterType.cs

------ StyleCop cancelled ------
```

Why do I get this message?  Did the process complete?  where do I find the results?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the "Error List" tab. I'm pretty sure you'll find that there are 1000 warnings. If that number is reached, StyleCop stops. And I'm not aware that you can change that number.

Fix the style violations or disable the rules you don't want/need to get below 1000. Then StyleCop will run to the end.

Comment: Where do I find the "Error List" tab? Do you mean the original VS one? That one still displays only 19 warnings after Style Cop cancelled the run, and most of them are definitely not produced by StyleCop. (Like "Property XYZ is never set" for objects filled via Reflection...)

Comment: Try switching filter from Build Only to Build + Intellisense

Answer (score 3):

StyleCop will be cancelled if the warnings are over 1000.
Another problem is the ErrorList by default is showing the error for "Build Only"

Below is the step to make the warning appear:
(*** Please note that The example below is using VS2017)

1) “StyleCop cancelled” with no reason states in the Output message:
[image]

2) Open the [Error List] tab and you will see nothing if the [Show issue generated] combo-box is "Build Only"
[image]

3) Change the [Show issue generated] combo-box to "Build +  Intellisense":
[image]

4) If you still see nothing, maybe the filter is on, click the "Clear All Filters" button to clear all filters:
[image]

5) And you should be able to see all of the warnings now:
[image]

6) You may want to reduce the warnings by removing the unwanted rules, right-click on the project and choose “Properties.” In the screen that just opened, select “Code Analysis”:
[image]

6) By default, the “Microsoft Managed Recommended Rules” will be selected. Click on “Open” and you’ll see a long list of rules you can select or deselect:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Project that's cancelling **StyleCop** and Choose StyleCop settings

[image: Step1]

Change maximum number of warnings before cancelling StyleCop

[image]